# Docker Networking Stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Currently I am trying to make my docker container's network stack be the same as my machine's in my docker-compose yml. I saw on the docker docs you can use "hostnet" to use your own network stack. I am using this but I keep getting an error saying...
services:
  xxxxx:
  xxxxx:
    networks: 
      hostnet:{}

networks:
  hostnet:
    external: true
    name: host

networks.hostnet value Additional properties are not allowed ('name' was unexpected)

What is wrong, and is there also a way to configure a docker compose file so that my container will have the same Network ID?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using:

```
network_mode: "host"
```

in the definition for your service. See Docker's compose file documenting for more details on this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode

Note that I personally consider this the option of last resort. If you can achieve your goals by publishing a single port instead of disabling the network namespacing features of docker, your solution will be more secure and portable.